# Condition_variable c++

Tags: c++

Есть простой пример использования Condition_variable:

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable



std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
int global_status = 0;

void print_id(int id) 
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);


    while (global_status == 0)
    {
        cv.wait(lck);
    }


    std::cout << "thread " << id << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    std::thread threads[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = std::thread(print_id, i);
    }
  


    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;


    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));            //Пауза, чтобы убедится, что потоки в ожидании.

{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    global_status = 1;
    cv.notify_all();
}

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Я все таки до сих пор не могу понять, зачем блокировать переменную global_status, когда я меняю ее значение ?

Comment: если переменная меняется в одном потоке, а в другом ее значение нужно прочитать, то должен быть какой-либо примитив синхронизации. Иначе может быть ай-ай-ай.

Comment: KoVadim, ну предположим я не поставил мьютекс на изменения значения global_status, я изменил global_status на 1 без мьютекса и другой поток считывает значение, не могу понять, что в данном случае может произойти. У меня же не два потока изменяют значение переменной, а только один.

Comment: @Optimus1 поток который читает может прочитать значение которое ещё в процессе изменения другим потоком - а это неопределённое поведение, почитайте про примитивы синхронизации

Comment: @Optimus1 мютексы и другие примитивы синхронизации всавляют барьеры памяти. А без них код может пойти совсем по другому пути. Один поток может "не увидеть изменение" переменной, которое произошло в другом потоке. Или увидеть не в том порядке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Между просмотром о состоянии переменной и командой ожидании сигнала находится критический участок кода.

Если поток ждёт сигнал, который был выслан до команды `wait`, то этот сигнал к нему так и не придёт. И будет ждать вечно. Сигнал получат только те процессы, что ждали его. А те процессы, что не успели встать в очередь будут ждать второго сигнала.

```
                   | while (global_status == 0)
global_status = 1; |
cv.notify_all();   |
                   | cv.wait(lck); вечно
```

В примере не зря поставили задержку 5 секунд. Без неё сигналы получат те, кто успел. А блокирование для отправки сигнала препятствует хотя-бы такой ситуации.

В реальных программах, сначала ставиться мютекс, проверяется флаг, что процесс ждёт сигнал, и потом если надо - отправляет. Только потом освобождается мютекс. Без блокировки будет неразбериха.

Comment: AlexGlebe, Спасибо за наглядный график, сразу понятно стало о чем речь.

Answer (score 2):

***Condition*** работает следющим образом:

1. при вызове `.wait(mtx)`, переданный   **mutex освобождается**, тем самым давая работать какому-то из потоков, ждущих указанного mutex-а, а сам thread приостанавливается.
2. при вызове `.notyfy_all()` все потоки, приостановленные на  condition variable, пробуждаются и тут же **пытаются захватить mutex**, который связан с этой переменной. Одному из них это удается и он **возвращается из** .wait() с **захваченным mutex**.

Т.е. mutex передаваемый в .wait() нужен для обеспечения сериализации работы потоков.

---

Возможно понимание этих мезанизмов будет лучше,  если почитать документацию, например, по [pthreads](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032r/index.html) (обычно лежащих в основе С++ multithreading)

Comment: avp, спасибо, я только немного не понял, после вызова.notyfy_all() потоки стремятся захватить мьютекс, кому то первому это удается сделать, он проверяет переменную global_status и если она не равна 0, то пропускает цикл и .wait. И вопрос, когда поток пропускает .wait, он уже освобождает мьютекс ? То есть код после цикла while уже выполняется каждым потоком параллельно или все еще под мьютексом ?

Comment: @Optimus1, после while под mutex-ом (т.е. у вас до конца функции будет работать один поток, а остальные будут ждать)